# How to remove this error in my program why it is coming?

Tags: java

[image]   This is the code that i have written this is showing error as shown in image help me.

```
class palindrome
{
public static void main(String args[])

  {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("nitin");
    System.out.println(sb);
    String sb1=sb.reverse();//error coming in this line why ?
    if(sb1.contentEquals(sb))
        {
        System.out.println("palindrome");
        }
    else
        {
        System.out.println("not a palindrome");
        }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Use StringBuilder instead, and remember to use `toString`to get strings from it (or StringBuffer. Same thing applies). And why not just read the error and fix what it tells you to fix...

Comment: Note that using some IDE would help avoiding such errors (check out eclipse or netbean or ...)

Comment: 1) "StringBuffer" != "String" (hence the error).  2) *Please* don't use annoying screen shots if you can simply cut/paste text.  OK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
sb.reverse()// This will return a reference to StringBuffer
```

to

```
sb.reverse().toString()//This will convert it to a String
```

Comment: As @RC suggested, use some IDE(Eclipse ?) if you quickly want to point out your errors.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert string buffer to string type before assigning to string

Try this

```
sb.reverse().toString()
```